# Flutter firestore sum all the field values according to daily record

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I am new to flutter and firestore development. I have a collection of **SalesRecord** and a field name called **SellingPrice**. How can i sum all the value of **SellingPrice** according to everyday records and print out all those sum value.

Update Code :-

```
FutureBuilder(
        future: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('SalesRecord').get(),
        builder: (BuildContext context,
            AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> querySnapshot) {
          if (querySnapshot.hasError) {
            return Text("Something went wrong");
          }

          // if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.data!.exists) {
          //   return Text("Document does not exist");
          // }

          if (querySnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            querySnapshot.data!.docs.forEach((doc) {
              sumTotal = sumTotal +
                  doc["SellingPrice"]; // make sure you create the variable sumTotal somewhere
            });
            return Text("Sum of all sells: ${sumTotal}");
          }

          return Text("loading");
        },
      ),
```

[image: Firestore]

[image: Error]

Comment: So if I get you right, every `document` contained withing your `SalesRecord` collection has a field called `SellingPrice` and you want to the get the sum of values for all `SellingPrice` fields

Comment: @TimothyOfie yes suppose i have 20 sales this day with the selling price of different value and i want to sum all today selling price and update the sum of selling price every day.

Comment: The answer below from @BJW would work fine, though it depends on what you want, for a clean experience you may choose to use `Firebase Cloud Functions` to automate summing of all `SellingPrice` values into a field at end of day, but for a quick and easy solution you can apply the answer from below sorted by date

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html and [https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#one-time-read) for detailed information. Following examples in there should bring you what you need.

For your case, you should use the `builder` inside the `FutureBuilder` try:

```
FutureBuilder(
    future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('SalesRecord')
        .get(),
    builder:
      (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> querySnapshot) {

    if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Text("Something went wrong");
    }

    if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.data!.exists) {
      return Text("Document does not exist");
    }

    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
      querySnapshot.data!.docs.forEach((doc) {
        sumTotal = sumTotal + doc["SellingPrice"]; // make sure you create the variable sumTotal somewhere
      });
      return Text("Sum of all sells: ${sumTotal}")
    }

    return Text("loading");
  },
),
```

Comment: Thankyou for your response i will try it.

Comment: I got this error NoSuchMethodError: '+' Dynamic call of null. Receiver: null Arguments: [3500]

Comment: did you initialize sumTotal somewhere else in your file?

Comment: Yes, but got this error

Comment: please add the full code and add a print statement to see what doc["SellingPrice"] is.